# Validation files always error on zip and mp3 file

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-5

What happen when I validation a file zip and mp3.

It always error, How can i do.

My validation code.

```
'my_files' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,mp4,mp3,mpga,zip,apk',
```

My form.

```
  Form::open(['files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'])
```

Response when var_dump file

```
object(Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile)[186]
  private 'test' (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile) => boolean false
  private 'originalName' (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile) => string 'My Files.zip' (length=17)
  private 'mimeType' (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile) => string 'application/octet-stream' (length=24)
  private 'size' (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile) => int 0
  private 'error' (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile) => int 1
  private 'pathName' (SplFileInfo) => string '' (length=0)
  private 'fileName' (SplFileInfo) => string '' (length=0)
```

Laravel V 5.3.30

Comment: OK, I found the problem. It because upload_max_filesize in php.ini

Comment: Could you please write an answer to your question and mark it as a solution?Someone in the future might be in same troubles as you were :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the problem. It because upload_max_filesize in php.ini